# SPF record, how do mailservers check?

Tags: java, email, spam, spf

we have issues with e-mail delivery for our customer portal and I`m wondering how exactly SPF works.

In our case, we have a portal, running on portal.oursite.com.
Customers can sent e-mail from our portal. E-mails are sent via JAVA and the e-mail is sent with the customers mailadres as sender. The mailserver we use is an external mailserver. So for example:

- customerx@hisdomain.com sents and e-mail
- mail is sent via portal.oursite.com
- portal.oursite.com uses mailserver smtp.anotherdomain.com to sent mail
- mail is sent to persony@gmail.com.

With this setup in mind, I wonder. If customerx@hisdomain.com experiences troubles with his mails being delivered to spambox of persony@gmail.com, where do we add the SPF record to optimize mail delivery?

Should the customer add smtp.anotherdomain.com SPF to his domain, or should we add it to oursite.com?

Answer (score 1):

smtp.anotherdomain.com needs to be added to the SPF policy for hisdomain.com, since a SPF record for a domain tells which mail-servers are allowed to send for that domain.

It's the same as when companies are using mailing services to send out newsletters etc, then they need to add the mailing service's outgoing SMTP servers to their SPF record. Ex: `v=spf1 mx include:constantcontact.com`

The users can either add the `a:smtp.anotherdomain.com` mechanism to they SPF record, or you can set up a record they can include like constantcontact.com has done (that way you can switch to using another outgoing mail server without the users having to change their SPF records).